# How to make subplots of various regions from a single plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I have a plot showing 2 sets of data using plt.plot() from matplotlib.pyplot. I am able to zoom in to different regions of the plot using  plt.axis([xmax,xmin,ymin,xmax]),  but I would like to make (at least 5) subplots of different regions in one output without having to create a new cell for each region. is this possible?

The code is a bit messy, but I have attached a screen shot of the plot instead. In this plot i would like to 'zoom' in to the region of vertical line: [image: Plot of data]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `matplotlib` feature `ConnectionPatch` , Documentation can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ConnectionPatch.html).

**P.S.:** I have use random data as you have no uploaded your dat file.

Please refer the code below.

```py
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch

font = {'family' : 'normal',
        'weight' : 'bold',
        'size'   :  18 }

plt.rc('font', **font)

# Define a function using lambda
stock = lambda A, amp, angle, phase: A * angle + amp * np.sin(angle + phase)

# Define parameters 
theta = np.linspace(0., 2 * np.pi, 250) # x-axis
np.random.seed(100)
noise = 0.2 * np.random.random(250)
y = stock(.1, .2, theta, 1.2) + noise # y-axis

# Create main container with size of 6x5
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0., left = 0, top = 1., right = 1)

# Create first axes, the top-left plot with green plot
sub1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1) # two rows, two columns, fist cell
sub1.plot(theta, y, lw=2, color = 'green');sub1.grid()
sub1.set_xlim(1, 2)
sub1.set_ylim(0.2, .5)
sub1.set_ylabel('y', labelpad = 15)

# Create second axes, the top-left plot with orange plot
sub2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2) # two rows, two columns, second cell
sub2.plot(theta, y, lw=2, color = 'orange');sub2.grid()
sub2.set_xlim(5, 6)
sub2.set_ylim(.4, 1)

# Create third axes, a combination of third and fourth cell
sub3 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,(3,4)) # two rows, two colums, combined third and fourth cell
sub3.plot(theta, y, lw=2, color = 'darkorchid', alpha = .7)
sub3.set_xlim(0, 6.5)
sub3.set_ylim(0, 1)
sub3.set_xlabel(r'$\theta$ (rad)', labelpad = 15)
sub3.set_ylabel('y', labelpad = 15)

# Create blocked area in third axes
sub3.fill_between((1,2), 0, 1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.2) # blocked area for first axes
sub3.fill_between((5,6), 0, 1, facecolor='orange', alpha=0.2) # blocked area for second axes

# Create left side of Connection patch for first axes
con1 = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(1, .2), coordsA=sub1.transData, 
                       xyB=(1, .3), coordsB=sub3.transData, color = 'green')
# Add left side to the figure
fig.add_artist(con1)

# Create right side of Connection patch for first axes
con2 = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(2, .2), coordsA=sub1.transData, 
                       xyB=(2, .3), coordsB=sub3.transData, color = 'green')
# Add right side to the figure
fig.add_artist(con2)

# Create left side of Connection patch for second axes
con3 = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(5, .4), coordsA=sub2.transData, 
                       xyB=(5, .5), coordsB=sub3.transData, color = 'orange')
# Add left side to the figure
fig.add_artist(con3)

# Create right side of Connection patch for second axes
con4 = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(6, .4), coordsA=sub2.transData, 
                       xyB=(6, .9), coordsB=sub3.transData, color = 'orange')
# Add right side to the figure
fig.add_artist(con4)

plt.grid()
```

[image: Output Image]